# Is there a way to add a tooltip to the p:fileUpload "delete file button"?

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, accessibility

I'm using PrimeFaces' `p:fileUpload` with attribute `mode="advanced"` so there are 3 buttons (Choose, Upload, Cancel) for uploading files. Below those buttons there is a field in which the chosen files appear after using the choose button. If a file with a correct data type is chosen, the file's name, size, a process bar for the upload and a button to delete the file appear.

**First question**: Is there a way to add a tooltip to this button?

Also, if a file with an incorrect data type is chosen, an error message appears in the field below the 3 buttons. This error message also has a button to remove the message. Neither the message itself nor its button are focusable by the tab key which makes it inaccessible for non-mouse users.

**Second question**: Is there a way to make the error message focusable by the tab key?

```html
<p:fileUpload id="fileUpload"
    fileUploadListener="#{ShowcaseHandler.handleFileUpload}" 
    mode="advanced"
    multiple="true"
    auto="false"
    dragDropSupport="false"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" chooseButtonTitle="Test"/>
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't provide images of my UI as my reputation on stackoverflow is not high enough :/

Comment: You can always post links

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip: See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/tooltips.xhtml for examples using PFv10. Also look at the PrimeFaces documentation for `p:tooltip`.

It appears tooltips were only supported natively in `fileUpload` from PrimeFaces v10 and I suspect from the question that you're using PF7 or earlier, in which case please see this PrimeFaces issue log for a potential workaround: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5831. Unfortunately the example does not cover the second delete file button that you mentioned, which is an element of a repeating row. You may need to submit an enhancement request to get this added to PrimeFaces natively.